# How to check whether a variable is numeric for a vector in R?

Tags: r

I have two questions.

```
  for (k in 1:iterations) {
      corr <- cor(df2_prod[,k], df2_qa[,k])

      ifelse(is.numeric(corr), next,
              ifelse((all(df2_prod[,k] == df2_qa[,k])) ), (corr <- 1), (corr <- 0))

      correlation[k,] <- rbind(names(df2_prod[k]), corr)

    }
```

This is my requirement -  I want to calculate correlation for  variables in a loop using the code `corr <- cor(df2_prod[,k], df2_qa[,k])`  If i receive a correlation value in number, I have to keep the value as it is.

Some time it happens that if two columns have the same values, i receive "NA" as  output for the vector "corr".

```
x   y
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1
1   1

corr
     [,1]
[1,]   NA
```

I am trying to handle in such a way that if "NA" is received, i will replace the values with "1" or "0".

My questions are:

1. When I check the class of "corr" vector, I am getting it as "matrix".   I want to check whether that is a number or not. Is there any other way other than checking is.numeric(corr)

   ```
   > class(corr)
   [1] "matrix"
   ```
2. I want to check if two columns has same value or not. Something like the code below. If it returns true, I want to proceed. But the way I have put the code in the loop is wrong. Could you please help me how this can be improved:
   `((all(df2_prod[,k] == df2_qa[,k]))`

Is there any effective way to do this?

I sincerely apologize the readers for the poorly framed question / logic. If you can show me pointers which can improve the code, I would be really thankful to you.

Comment: please provide `dput(df2_prod)` and `dput(df2_qa)`

Comment: wouldn't `corr <- cor(df2_prod[, 1:k], df2_qa[, 1:k])` give you the first result you want (all correlation coefficients) ? and actually, you wouldn't have to care about the `NA` values because, when used with several variables, `cor` output 1 in case of equal variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
You basically want to avoide NAs, right? So you could check the result with is.na().

```
a <- rep(1, 5)
b <- rep(1, 5)
if(is.na(cor(a, b))) cor.value <- 1
```

2.You could count how many times the element of a is equal to the element of b with sum(a==b) and check whether this amount is equal to the amount of elements in a (or b) --> length(a)

```
if(sum(a==b) == length(a)) cor.value <- 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An example to explain how the `cor` function works:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(v1=1:10, v2=rnorm(10), v3=rnorm(10), v4=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(w1=rnorm(10), w2=1:10, w3=rnorm(10))
```

Here, the first variable of `df1` is equal to the second variable of `df2`. Function `cor` directly applied on the first 3 variables of each data.frame gives:

```
cor(df1[, 1:3], df2[, 1:3])
#           w1         w2         w3
#v1 -0.4603659  1.0000000  0.1078796
#v2  0.6730196 -0.2602059 -0.3486367
#v3  0.2713188 -0.3749826 -0.2520174
```

As you can notice, the correlation coefficient between `w2` and `v1` is `1`, not `NA`.

So, in your case, `cor(df2_prod[, 1:k], df2_qa[, 1:k])` should provide you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is an example df1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5), df2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1). When I correlate cor(df1,df2), the answer is NA. I was trying to replace this NA with 0 or 1 according to my requirement.

Comment: @Arun, with your definition, `df1` and `df2` are vectors, not data.frames, hence the `NA`

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my understanding.